# how to set margin on imageview using code in android?

Tags: android, imageview, runtime, margin

I am trying to create a layout at runtime and then I want to add some imageview using looping at runtime. but the problem is that the margin I am giving using LayoutParams is not working at all. I have tried and searched alot but didn't find any solution. I am attaching my code also.

```
RelativeLayout ll_main_image = new RelativeLayout(activity);
        ll_main_image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                width,
                width));


        for (int i = 0; i < al.get(position).al.size(); i++) {

            //creating layout for tags
            ImageView view_tag = new ImageView(activity);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            int int_margin_left = (int)(((Double.parseDouble(al.get(position).al.get(i).str_x_pos))/100)*width);
            int int_margin_top  = (int)(((Double.parseDouble(al.get(position).al.get(i).str_y_pos))/100)*width);

            System.out.println("margins perc " + al.get(position).al.get(i).str_x_pos + " / " + al.get(position).al.get(i).str_y_pos + " / " + width);
            System.out.println("margins " + int_margin_left + " / " + int_margin_top + " / " + width);

            lp.setMargins(int_margin_left, int_margin_top, 0, 0);
            view_tag.setLayoutParams(lp);

            view_tag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tag_light);
            ll_main_image.addView(view_tag);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using LinearLayout.LayoutParams where the layout is RelativeLayout. change to RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, it should work.